# Bootstrap and Angular JS button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this bootstrap and Angular JS app. I am using the following directive to show active navigation links:

```
mainControl.directive("myDataToggle", function(){
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var e = angular.element(element);
        e.on('click', function(){
            e.parent().parent().children().removeClass('active');
            e.parent().addClass("active");
        })
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };
});
```

Problem is this works fine in the nav, but if I have a button link that links to the separate sections of the app, the main nav at the top does not get updated To reflect which view I am in?

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you use `ng-class`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the class when you're clicking the link, not when you are navigating.
I presume you're using the ngRoute. If so you can try this approach:

Provide a name for your routes

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        name: 'home'
    }).
    when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        name: 'about'
    });
```

Than add $route to your main controller, and pass it on to $scope

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $route) {
    $scope.$route = $route;
}
```

Now you can add the active class using ng-class

```
<a ng-class="{active: $route.current.name == 'home'}"> Home </a>
<a ng-class="{active: $route.current.name == 'about'}"> About </a>
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/mao8kx0L/2/

Comment: oops, I meant to write that instead of "routeprovider". I'll update my answer.
so yeah, it'll work with that. 

There is

Comment: @rob you could also use ui-route... they take care of this for you:
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active

but this option wil definitely work for you

Comment: how would the urls look, that example link does not explain it well?

Comment: abit confused, i am actually using ui-router

Comment: I've tried to create a jsfiddle with the "ui-sref-active" but for some reason it's not working. (I left that on the "contact" link)

The solution as mentioned before will also work with ui-router as shown in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/mao8kx0L/4/